# Убрать пропущенные значения в цикле

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, обработка-данных, nan

Подсчитываю точечно-биссериальный коэффициент таким кодм:

```
def tbk(col):
        tbk_ras = stats.pointbiserialr(col, df['Общий'])
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({"statistic": [tbk_ras[0]],
                           "pvalue": [tbk_ras[1]]})

        return df1.assign(column=col.name)

res = pd.concat([tbk(df[col]) for col in df.columns], ignore_index=True)

print(res)
```

Код рабочий, но если есть пропущенные значения, возникают проблемы.
[Например, на таких данных](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CHGpbj7b7o4hUdd7bGToYc16K9glIUqbvj8ssb9qP-I/edit?usp=sharing) , где для рассчета `pointbiserialr` попарно берется первый столбец с каждым последующим, считаться не будет, т.к. есть пропущенные значения. Значит, в самом цикле в каждой паре столбцов нужно удалять те строки, в которых встречаются `NaNs`.
Я пробую это делать при помощи `.isna()` , но, очевидно, что-то делаю не так, потому что получаю неправильные значения.
Помогите, пожалуйста! Какой метод я могу использовать, чтобы решить свою задачу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте создать булеву маску строк с непустыми (`not NaN`) значениями в функции и использовать ее для фильтрации значений обоих столбцов:

```
def tbk(col):
    mask = col.notna()
    tbk_ras = stats.pointbiserialr(col.loc[mask], df.loc[mask, 'Общий'])
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({"statistic": [tbk_ras[0]],
                       "pvalue": [tbk_ras[1]]})

    return df1.assign(column=col.name)

res = pd.concat([tbk(df[col]) for col in df.columns], ignore_index=True)

print(res)
```

результат:

```
In [113]: print(res)
   statistic        pvalue column
0   1.000000  0.000000e+00  Общий
1   0.306734  1.559845e-06     n1
2   0.460923  8.117419e-15     n2
3   0.529065  4.482090e-28     n3
4   0.507567  9.656675e-16     n4
5   0.583858  4.933563e-20     n5
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло! Изучу Ваше решение